# lower bound for the principal eigenvalue of laplacian in terms of volume

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality, spectral-theory

I am wondering if one can obtain a lower bound for the principal eigenvalue of laplacian on a closed manifold in terms of its volume. If this does not hold in general, would there be some special manifold where such bound exist? For example this is certainly true for $S^1,$ but I guess something could go weird in higher dimension.

Comment: The groundbreaking result on this is the Cheeger inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant). You can get a lower bound on the Cheeger constant on a closed Riemannian manifold if you assume a lower bound on volume, a lower bound on Ricci curvature, and an upper bound on diameter. There are many generalizations of this, but I don't recall what the weakest known assumptions are.

Comment: Is it possible to get a bound without curvature assumption?

Comment: No. The Wikipedia page also mentions Buser’s inequality, which gives an upper bound on $\lambda_1$ in terms of the Cheeger constant. It is easy to construct a Riemannian manifold with volume 1 and arbitrarily small Cheeger constant if you do not assume a lower bound on curvature.